# How to properly populate a document in a collection (model) of Mongoose data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the context of this exercise I try to link several questions to a Quiz and I can't manage to populate my documents (question) well in the collection (Quizz)

Models / **quizz.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const modelName = 'Quizz';
const collectionName = modelName.toLowerCase();

const QuizzSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, },
    questions: [
      { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Question" 
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

QuizzSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
export default mongoose.model(modelName, QuizzSchema, collectionName);
```

Models / **question.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const modelName = 'Question';
const collectionName = modelName.toLowerCase();

const QuestionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _quizz: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: "Quizz"
    },
    title: { type: String, required: true, },
    description: { type: String, required: true},
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

QuestionSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
export default mongoose.model(modelName, QuestionSchema, collectionName);
```

Services / **quizz.js**

I tried to add the .populate () method everywhere on my getOneQuizz method but it doesn't work. Where should I put it exactly.

```
export const getOneQuizz = async (id) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Quizz.findOne({ _id: id},
      '-updatedAt -createdAt',
      {},
      (err, item) => {
        if(err) {
          reject(utils.buildErrObject(402, err.message));

          return;
        }
        resolve(item);
    }
  )
})
```

Controllers / **quizz.js**

```
export const fetchOne = async (req, res, next) => {
  getOneQuizz(req.params.id)
    .then(data => res.json({data}))
    .catch(err => utils.handleError(res, err));
};
```

Routes / quizz.js

```
router.get('/:id', quizzController.fetchOne);
```

In my database I see the data that has been correctly added
[Quizz collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKNa0.jpg)

[Retrive data from PAI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmKRr.jpg)

My API returns the quizzes to me but I can't access the question data and I can't understand why. Would I skip something. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Probably because Mongoose isn't returning you lean JSON data, but one of its weirdos. To get simple JSON, add `.lean()`. Also simplified syntax : `const item = await Quizz.findOne({_id:id}).lean().exec()`

Comment: Always the same result is what you saw **the captures** (of the database and the postman) which I joined to the question?